# WPF UserControl with a url as dependencyproperty

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm creating a wpf usercontrol which is basically a button that's supposed to open a document. I want to create it so anyone can be able to put the url of this document in the xaml. Is this possible?

Edit: I've added a dependencyproperty to store the url, but it throws an exception whenever I try to build it. The xaml looks like this:

```
<controls:HelpButton WidthAndHeight="40" HelpDocUrl="somUrl"/>
```

and my code behind for the property looks like this:

```
public string HelpDocUrl    
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(HelpDocUrlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HelpDocUrlProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty HelpDocUrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HelpDocUrl", typeof(string), typeof(HelpButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dependency property of the code-behind class of your `UserControl`:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Url", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Url;
        //...
    }
}
```

...that any consumer of your control can set as usual:

```
<local:UserControl1 Url="http://...." />
```